# How to extend HTML attribute interfaces when designing reasonml react components?

Tags: reason, reason-react

I'm learning reasonml and quite excited about it. Something I often do in typescript react code is:

```
type Props = React.HTMLProps<HTMLButtonElement> & { foo: boolean }
const SuperButton: React.FC<Props> = (props) => <button {/* stuff with props */ />
```

In this regard, I communicate to my users as a component library provider that this button extends normal HTML button attributes.

How can I express and extend normal html component attributes in my components?

I see that reason explicitly doesn't support spreading props: https://github.com/reasonml/reason-react/blob/master/docs/props-spread.md.

I do see that there is a composition strategy: [How to compose props across component in reason-react bindings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47134445/how-to-compose-props-across-component-in-reason-react-bindings), but not sure how to marry that up with normal HTML element component stuffs.

Any recommendations? Thanks!

Comment: Check this [page](https://reasonml.github.io/reason-react/docs/en/clone-element)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to do something similar using `ReasonReact.cloneElement`, as Amirali hinted. The idea is to split up your component's props and the HTML button's props into two separate parameters for your component, render your button, and then clone it while also injecting the extra button props.

[This page](https://reasonml.github.io/reason-react/docs/en/adding-data-props) shows a component which encapsulates this clone-and-injection functionality:

```
module Spread = {
  [@react.component]
  let make = (~props, ~children) =>
    ReasonReact.cloneElement(children, ~props, [||]);
};
```

Now, you can use this `Spread` component for your `SuperButton` component:

```
module SuperButton = {
  [@react.component]
  let make = (~foo, ~htmlButtonProps) =>
    <Spread props=htmlButtonProps>
      <button> (foo ? "YES" : "NO")->React.string </button>
    </Spread>;
};
```

The `htmlButtonProps` prop will contain the regular HTML button props, while separately `foo` is your component's specific prop. The component can be used like this:

```
<SuperButton foo=true htmlButtonProps={"autofocus": true} />
```

Small housekeeping note: you don't actually need to define the modules with the `module` keyword. If you want you can put them in separate files called `Spread.re` and `SuperButton.re`. Reason files automatically become modules.

Comment: Thanks for the share. Ya, that could work. Shucks, I still feel like there's gotta be some strategy that doesn't involve a `cloneElement` call. If I'm designing a component library, this strategy seems like like it won't scale. I need extend underlying HTML interfaces, and having all my primitives invoke a cloneElement I think is probably a bit too heavy handed.